# Preventing Deadlocks in transactions

Tags: sql, database-deadlocks

One of our developers has come up with a theory for eliminating deadlocks and I am wondering if anyone else has tried this solution.  Does it actually work?  Is there merit in the concept?

> If deadlocks continue, then I would figure out an appropriate table to do a fake-update on immediately after BEGIN TRAN to cause micro- blocking, and do that fake-update in both processes, making sure that the trx is also small in scope.  I would guess in these cases that the syCustomers table would be good to use, and the fake update should be done by CustomerKey.  Scope-wise both processes would then need to only do work within the BEGIN TRAN trx for one CustomerKey only and then COMMIT TRAN, then do the next account.

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE syCustomers SET FakeLock = FakeLock WHERE CustomerKey = @CustomerKey
<now do the real updates as required>
COMMIT
```

He is convinced this does something to the locking logic that prevent deadlocks.  Your thoughts?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: The usual way to avoid deadlocks is to acquire the locks for the difference rows in the same order in all transactions.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. There is too much left out here and there’s no way for us to tell if you’re representing the idea accurately.